# C# DataContract Serialization, how to deserialize to already existing instance

Tags: c#, serialization, netdatacontractserializer

I have a class, which holds a static dictionary of all existing instances, which are defined at compile time.

Basically it looks like this:

```
[DataContract]
class Foo
{
  private static Dictionary<long, Foo> instances = new Dictionary<long, Foo>();

  [DataMember]
  private long id;

  public static readonly Foo A = Create(1);
  public static readonly Foo B = Create(2);
  public static readonly Foo C = Create(3);

  private static Foo Create(long id)
  {
    Foo instance = new Foo();
    instance.id = id;
    instances.Add(instance);
    return instance;
  }

  public static Foo Get(long id)
  {
    return instances[id];
  }    

}
```

There are other fields, and the class is derived, but this doesn't matter for the problem.

Only the `id` is serialized. When an instance of this type is deserialized, I would like to get the instance that has been created as the static field (`A`, `B` or `C`), using `Foo.Get(id)` instead of getting a new instance.

Is there a simple way to do this? I didn't find any resources which I was able to understand.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

During deserialization it (AFAIK) always uses a new object (`FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject`), but to get it to substitute the objects *after* deserialization (but before they are returned to the caller), you can implement [`IObjectReference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iobjectreference.aspx), like so:

```
[DataContract]
class Foo : IObjectReference { // <===== implement an extra interface
    object IObjectReference.GetRealObject(StreamingContext ctx) {
        return Get(id);
    }
    ...snip
}
```

done... proof:

```
static class Program {
    static void Main() {
        Foo foo = Foo.Get(2), clone;
        DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Foo));
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) { // clone it via DCS
            ser.WriteObject(ms, foo);
            ms.Position = 0;
            clone = (Foo)ser.ReadObject(ms);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(foo, clone)); // true
    }
}
```

Note there are some extra notes on this for partial trust scenarios on MSDN, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731923.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and the best solution that I found was adding some wrapper class, that was managing instances of the one needed to be serialized.

I am not sure about the exact signature with Contracts. I used SerializableAttribute, and with it i looked smth. like that:

```
[Serializable]
class FooSerializableWrapper : ISerializable
{
    private readonly long id;

    public Foo Foo
    {
        get
        {
            return Foo.Get(id);
        }
    }

    public FooSerializableWrapper(Foo foo)
    {
        id = foo.id;
    }

    protected FooSerializableWrapper(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        id = info.GetInt64("id");
    }


    void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("id", id);
    }

}
```

Comment: I actually don't want the using class be concerned, because `Foo` is a very central class and used from many other types.

Comment: How would this implementation look like?

Comment: Ok, looks promising. Does it also means that I need to use the `FooSerializableWrapper` instead of `Foo` in all my classes? This would be very bad... Or can I plug in the wrapper somehow?

Comment: You need to use the FooSerializableWrappe in any place where Foo needs to be serialized/deserialized

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to get a step towards what you are looking for using [OnDeserializingAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializingattribute.aspx).  However, that will probably only let you set properties (so you could have what amounts to a Copy method that populates all the properties of the current instance using your static instance.

I think if you actually want to return your static instances, you'd probably have to write your own Deserializer...

Untested, but I would assume you could implement a deserializer pretty easily like this:

```
public class MyDeserializer : System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer
{
    protected override object Deserialize(System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader reader)
    {
        Foo obj = (Foo)base.Deserialize(reader);
        return Foo.Get(obj.id);
    }
}
```

Note that you'll have to do something about getting the ID since it is private in your code; Also this assumes you are using XML serialization; Replace the inheritance with whatever you actually are using.  And finally, this means you'll have to instantiate this type when deserializing your objects, which may involve changing some code and/or configuration.

Comment: I know the `OnDeserializing` attribute. It doesn't allow creating the instance, because it is called on the already created instance. There is also the `ISerializable` interface and other stuff, but i can't find a solution for this.

Comment: See additional info regarding building your own Deserializer.

Comment: I need it for WCF (NetDataContractSerializer). I *could* use another serializer for the whole application, but I would like to keep the infrastructure as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

No problem, just use 2 classes. In getObject method you get your existing object

```
[Serializable]
public class McRealObjectHelper : IObjectReference, ISerializable 
{
    Object m_realObject;
    virtual object getObject(McObjectId id)
    {
        return id.GetObject();
    }
    public McRealObjectHelper(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        McObjectId id = (McObjectId)info.GetValue("ID", typeof(McObjectId));
        m_realObject = getObject(id);
        if(m_realObject == null)
            return;
        Type t = m_realObject.GetType();
        MemberInfo[] members = FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(t, context);
        List<MemberInfo> deserializeMembers = new List<MemberInfo>(members.Length);
        List<object> data = new List<object>(members.Length);
        foreach(MemberInfo mi in members)
        {
            Type dataType = null;
            if(mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field)
            {
                FieldInfo fi = mi as FieldInfo;
                dataType = fi.FieldType;
            } else if(mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property){
                PropertyInfo pi = mi as PropertyInfo;
                dataType = pi.PropertyType;
            }
            try
            {
                if(dataType != null){
                    data.Add(info.GetValue(mi.Name, dataType));
                    deserializeMembers.Add(mi);
                }
            }
            catch (SerializationException)
            {
                //some fiels are missing, new version, skip this fields
            }
        }
        FormatterServices.PopulateObjectMembers(m_realObject, deserializeMembers.ToArray(), data.ToArray());
    }

    public object GetRealObject( StreamingContext context )
    {
        return m_realObject;
    }
    [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.SerializationFormatter)]
    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
    }
}

public class McRealObjectBinder: SerializationBinder
{
    String assemVer;
    String typeVer;
    public McRealObjectBinder(String asmName, String typeName)
    {
        assemVer = asmName;
        typeVer = typeName;
    }
    public override Type BindToType( String assemblyName, String typeName ) 
    {
        Type typeToDeserialize = null;
        if ( assemblyName.Equals( assemVer ) && typeName.Equals( typeVer ) )
        {
            return typeof(McRealObjectHelper);
        }
        typeToDeserialize = Type.GetType( String.Format(  "{0}, {1}", typeName, assemblyName ) );
        return typeToDeserialize;
    }
}
```

Then, when deserialize:

```
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter(null, context);
bf.Binder = new McRealObjectBinder(YourType.Assembly.FullName, YourType.FullName);
bf.Deserialize(memStream);
```